# Response.Redirect is showing /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am struct with redirect thing in my asp.net web application with c#.

when i enter the login page and complete all the fuctionalities and then redirect to next page the url `/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f` is been shown.

So i googled the issue and added these lines in web.config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="43280" />
    </authentication>
```

But still the same url is been displayed when i do  `Response.Redirect("SelectApp.aspx");` where in `SelectApp.aspx` is a webform placed under Account folder where in the `Login.aspx` is also placed.

```
   protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserMaster where USER_NAME =@username and USER_PWD1=@password", con);
            //string enPwd = Encode(Password.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UserName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Password.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("SelectApp.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
            }
        }
```

I have added the Code above. But i am not getting any solution for my problem.

Comment: please give your code of login method

Comment: Is the user authenticated? If not, the framework will redirect to the loginpage.

Comment: Just have a hunch but still wanna make sure if this works or not, In above where you are redirecting you are passing relative URL instead try passing absolute URL and see if you still getting `ReturnUrl=%2f` issue.

Comment: Yakup's answer is what you need. If the auth cookie isn't set, you can redirect anywhere you want but asp considers you to be not authenticated and redirects back to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

Before you redirect to `"SelectApp.aspx"`. Try adding `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName.Text.Trim(), false);`

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, try: Response.Redirect("SelectApp.aspx", false);

Mostly because ending the response could interfere with the authentication...

I haven't tested this, but I recall running into a similar issue. Setting the 'endResponse' parameter to 'false' did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check the authorization tag of your web.config, maybe even being authenticated you have any restrictions on the type:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users = "*" />
</authorization>
```